# Как автоматически подогнать высоту картинки?

Tags: php

Нужно уменьшить картинку пропорционально, но, указав лишь ее ширину, а высота чтобы определилась автоматически, исходя из размера ширины. Такое возможно?

```
    $src = imagecreatefrompng($iii);
    $img = getimagesize($iii);
    $width = $img[0];
    $height = $img[1];
    $resize_width = ($width*50)/100;
    $resize_height = ($height*50)/100;
    $new = ImageCreateTrueColor($resize_width,$resize_height);
    imagealphablending($new, false);
    imagesavealpha($new, true);
    ImageCopyResampled($new, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $resize_width, $resize_height, $width, $height);

    imagepng($new, './img'.p($_POST['title']).'.png', 9, PNG_ALL_FILTERS);
    imagedestroy(array($img,$src,$new));
```

`ImageCopyResampled($new, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $resize_width, $resize_height, $width, $height);` вот ту например указать не `$resize_height` а `auto` но так нельзя)

Comment: И что мой код делает в вашем вопросе?

Comment: Чтобы посмотрели что я не так делаю, просто как то не правильно я это делаю)

Comment: Попробуйте использовать вот эту библиотеку https://github.com/claviska/SimpleImage

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пользуюсь такими вычислениями

```
$size = getimagesize($file); // берем размеры картинки из файла
$xr = ($width == 0) ? 1 : $width / $size[0]; // тут $width нужная ширина, 0 - не учитывать (расчет автоматом из нужно высоты)
$yr = ($height == 0) ? 1 : $height / $size[1]; // тут $height нужная высота, 0 - не учитывать (расчет автоматом из нужно ширины)
$r = min($xr, $yr, 1);
$width = round($size[0] * $r); // $width - ширина на выходе 
$height = round($size[1] * $r); // $height - высота на выходе
```

P.S. Да. Если заданы и ширина, и высота на входе, то вычисляются новые размеры картинки с сохранением пропорций от старых размеров, но чтобы новые размеры вписались в требуемые ширину/высоту.

Comment: на выходе получаю число 300, оригинальный размер картинки, что я не так сделал?

Comment: @emtecif, так не надо переменные заменять числами, да еще неправильно.

Comment: Спасибо, работает